# Getting 0 in formulas with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel

So I'm using PHPExcel in my Laravel project, and in some places I have different formulas, not specified ones, but custom math, like `E10*5/E8` etc.

And I get zeros in these cells after download, all the formulas are saved, but are not being pre-calculated.

As far as I understand, I need to set `setPreCalculatedFormulas` to `true`, but I cannot find the place to insert this line. My code looks as follows:

```
public function get_excel($id)
    {
        Excel::create('table_'.$id, function($excel) {
          $excel->setCreator("Ana");
          $excel->setLastModifiedBy("Ana");
          <...>
          $excel->sheet('sheet', function($sheet) {
              $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow<...>
          });
        })->download("xsls");
    }
```

And whereever I try to put this setPreCalculatedFormulas, I get an error

> LaravelExcelException in LaravelExcelWriter.php line 628: [ERROR]
>   Writer method [setPreCalculateFormulas] does not exist.

Where is my mistake? Would really appreciate any possible help!

**UPD**: I've changed '`calculate`' and `setPreCalculateFormulas` to true in LaravelExcelWriter configs, but the result is still the same.

**UPD2**: I've tried to add `$sheet->getCell("K".$row)->getCalculatedValue();` after inserting a formula, but it did not help

**UPD3**: predefined formulas like SUM get calculated, but custom ones don't, that's weird

**Happy End:** I've added `Config::set(['excel.export.calculate' => true]);` at the start of my controller, and this one worked out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring calculated values when reading in Excel file with PHPExcel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533090/ignoring-calculated-values-when-reading-in-excel-file-with-phpexcel)

Comment: yeah, I've seen this post, but I can't adjust this info to my case

Comment: @Coffee do you fix your problem? I have similar with cakephp

Comment: @inye yes, just had to change a config Config::set(['excel.export.calculate' => true]);